# How to get data of current state in dataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to get the current data in **dataTables**, for example, when I clicked the sort button, the dataTables is sorted. And I want to get the sorted data.

I have tried `.data()` function, however data is in the init state.

And my data source is dom, dataTables version is 1.10.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to find a way, actually not the best way.

```
var data = Array();
title = ['titleA', 'titleB', 'titleC'];
data.push(title);
var i = 0;
var cell = Array();
$("#dataTable").DataTable().cells().data().each( function (d) {
    cell.push(d)
    if(i % title.length == title.length - 1) {
        data.push(cell)
        cell = Array();
    }   
    i++;
}); 
console.log(data);
```

Any better way is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

Here's a good reference..
[Just CLICK here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)

I hope it will help.